# Select DOM for mainContentOfPage with cssSelector: "The property value is not recognized by Google for an object of type WebPageElement."

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I would like to integrate the structured data [`mainContentOfPage`](http://schema.org/mainContentOfPage) with the JSON-LD format.

I need to specify the part of the DOM, so I use the [`cssSelector`](https://pending.schema.org/cssSelector) property.

This is what the data looks like:

```json
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@type": "WebPage",
    "mainContentOfPage": {
        "@type": "WebPageElement",
        "cssSelector": "#landingPage",
    },
}
```

The structured data test tool gives me a warning:

> The property *value* is not recognized by Google for an object of type *WebPageElement*.

How can I do this?

You can test this code in the SDTT:

```html
<html lang="fr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script type="application/ld+json">
    {"@context":"http://schema.org/","@type":"WebPage","mainContentOfPage":{"@type":"WebPageElement","cssSelector":"#landingPage"}}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="landingPage">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In non molestie libero.</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to also markup `landingPage` so that there is a link between the first item (WebPage/mainContentOfPage) and the second item (landingPage).

Comment: I don't know how to do with the JSON-LD format, would you have an example please?

Answer (score 0):

cssSelector is not part of schema.org core yet. You can't use it as part of schema.org yet, only when it's moved from [pending](https://pending.schema.org) to core.

> The term 'cssSelector' is not in the schema.org core vocabulary, but is defined in an extension:
>
> - pending: cssSelector

https://schema.org/cssSelector

Comment: The following code is valid, It uses "cssSelector" : 

```{
    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@type": "WebPage",
    "speakable": {
        "@type": "SpeakableSpecification",
        "cssSelector": "#landingPage",
    },
}```